# Deployment fail on windows azure with Github source control

Tags: azure, deployment, github

I linked my website on Azure to Github respository and it was working good for a while. Recently, it starts deployment failing with the log.

```
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.2.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.3.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.4.0 does not point to a valid object! 
error: refs/tags/v1.6.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.7.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.2.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.3.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.4.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.6.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.7.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.2.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.3.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.4.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.6.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.7.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.2.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.3.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.4.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.6.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v1.7.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: Could not read 4a49af0a0cb64a0a0415734b11772d6df18561fb
error: Could not read 5fe173ec7c37d3674f9c70b992333503c214ba10
error: Could not read 390c8cbd527c8e707c51e25142e54421f4dd3948
error: Could not read 32f081f8b901425fd1e8898478f0551970bee0f5
error: Could not read 4fdf82f47ded8df543443a6b692d0a16b7d8ad51
error: Could not read 0f1c8929f6885f3df3a0009136891c46c9f98378
error: Could not read 6050db408f473e144d557c619e0bf749fbbbaa75
remote: Counting objects: 1132, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/261)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (3/261)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (6/261)   [K
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there may be some corruption on your git repo on Azure. To investigate, use the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console). From the console, go to the `site\repository` folder and run basic git commands like `git status` to see how they fare.

If that doesn't help, you can go to the Dashboard tab in the Azure portal and delete your git repo, then reconnect to github.

Comment: I tried disconnecting and connecting to Github many times, didn't help. Can I delete site\respository directory from Kudu console ? thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly try to delete the repository folder. But the act of disconnecting from Github should have done that already. Might be worth checking that in Kudu console after disconnecting (and before reconnecting).

Comment: Deleting the contents of the repository folder (and for extra measure the wwwroot folder) and reconnecting github finally did the trick for me